# nodered write to file without inject node

Tags: node-red

I have a feeling that storing data in a file works only through an inject node that has to be triggered manually.

I would like the data to be stored as soon as new data comes in from a function node though. The trigger node didn't work either.

The msg.payload of a TCP output node should be connected to an file input node, like this:

[{"id":"54b54be5.ca3de4","type":"tcp in","z":"4d18212.60a81e","name":"listening","server":"server","host":"","port":"9100","datamode":"stream","datatype":"utf8","newline":"","topic":"","base64":false,"x":296,"y":206,"wires":[["90434ae1.aa9b98"]],"outputLabels":["node"]},{"id":"90434ae1.aa9b98","type":"file","z":"4d18212.60a81e","name":"","filename":"examplefile","appendNewline":true,"createDir":false,"overwriteFile":"false","x":575,"y":219,"wires":[]}]

Comment: Edit the question to actually show us what you have tried. As it stands its far too vague

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you have no need for an inject node, just wire the function node to the file out node and it will write what ever the function node output in `msg.payload` to the file.

You do need something upstream of the function node to cause it to run, the examples tend to use an inject node because it makes it easy to test, but what you actually use depends on the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: Thanks. Still cannot get it to work. A TCP output node should connect to a file node:

Comment: What you've posted will work fine, assuming something connects to the port 9100 and sends it a stream of characters. You've not set a delimiter so I'm not 100% sure how the TCP in node will chunk up the incoming data.

Comment: You should probably also set a full path in the file name setting to be 100% sure where the file will be written to.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I know where I went wrong now. I had a function before the write-to-file-node that did not return a msg.payload object, but an object with another name.